# How to find build time of docker image?

Tags: docker

I tried `docker image history`, `docker image inspect` but could not find how long it took to build an image locally on my system.

Though I found the image created time, not when it started building.

Is there any docker command that could help find it?

Comment: I don't think this information is part of the image, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the build time is recorded in the image.
I think your best bet is to measure it yourself.

```
time docker build -t <tag> .
```

Or I saw other more granular ways to do it in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46166293/how-to-measure-docker-build-steps-duration)